# Cabeçalho fixo no topo após rolagem de página

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

```
<header class="cabecalho">
        <div class="cabecalho_banner">
            <h1 class="cabecalho_banner-titulo">titu<span>lo</span></h1>
            <p class="cabecalho_banner-paragrafo">paragrafo<strong>front-end</strong></p>
            <a class="cabecalho_banner-botao" href="#sobre">veja meu trabalho</a>
        </div>
        <nav class="cabecalo_navegacao" id="cabecalho">
            <ul class="cabecalo_navegacao-conteiner">
                <li class="cabecalo_navegacao-link"><a href="#">início</a></li>
                <li class="cabecalo_navegacao-link"><a href="#">sobre</a></li>
                <li class="cabecalo_navegacao-link"><a href="#">contato</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

O seguinte código javaScript não está funcionando

```
    const cabecalho = document.getElementById("cabecalho");
    const cabecalhoTop = cabecalho.pageYOffset();//erro aparece aqui

    function fixarCabecalhoTopo() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= cabecalhoTop) {
        cabecalho.classList.add("cabecalho--fixed");
    } else {
        cabecalho.classList.remove("cabecalho--fixed");
    }
}
```

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    fixarCabecalhoTopo();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No próprio CSS você pode fixar.

```css
.cabecalho {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Mas quiser fazer via javascript:

```js
cabecalho.style.positon = "fixed"
```

Comment: O que eu queria era fixar o cabeçalho no topo após um determinado ponto da página

Answer (score -2):

é possível fazer isso utilizando o CSS através da propriedade "position". Como você quer que ele seja fixado apenas coloque "position: fixed;"

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).